# How to convert relative path to absolute path in android?

Tags: java, android, relative-path, absolute-path

I want to convert relative path to absolute path, like this:

from: `foo/bar/../Images/cover.jpg`

to: `foo/Images/cover.jpg`

How can I do that?

Comment: Both of those are relative paths.

Comment: Other than what CommonsWare said, this is in no way different in Android compared to java, so I'm going to mark this as a duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you @M.Prokhorov.